# stock managing e-commerce symfony

Tags: php, symfony, e-commerce, stock

I'm doing an e-commerce in Symfony and for my cart, I would like to manage the stocks, I have the stock parameter in my product table and I would like that when there is 0 product in stock, we can't add it to the cart, and each time we add a product, it loses 1 in the stock, do you have an idea of how to do it?

My function in CartService :

```
 public function add(int  $id)
    {
        $cart = $this->session->get('cart', []);
        if (array_key_exists($id, $cart)) {
            $cart[$id]++;
        } else {
            $cart[$id] = 1;
        }
        $this->session->set('cart', $cart);
    }
```

My function in CartController

```
 public function add($id, Request $request)
    {

        $product = $this->productRepository->find($id);
        if (!$product) {

            throw $this->createNotFoundException("le produit $id n'éxiste pas");
        }
        $this->cartService->add($id);

        $this->addFlash('success', "le produit a bien été ajouté au panier");
        if ($request->query->get('returnToCart')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('cart_index');
        }
        if ($request->query->get('returnToHome')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('product');
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('cart_index', []);
    }
```

And stock in my entity Product

```
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $stock;

 public function getStock(): ?int
    {
        return $this->stock;
    }

    public function setStock(int $stock): self
    {
        $this->stock = $stock;

        return $this;
    }
```

Thank you for your response !

Comment: In your *CartController*, you could perform a check first, like `if (!$product->getStock()) {...}` (if it's null or zero, it is false) then add a flash message with a return redirect..

Comment: Thank you ! That's work good ! But if I add a product, i would like the stock lose 1 (decrement) and it's at that point that i'm loss, have you an idea ?

Comment: Because if I try :                                                                                                                       
                if($product->getStock() > 0){
                $product->getStock() --;
                };  I Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: You can make the stock a variable `$stock = $product->getStock();` then still check like i shown above with `if (!$stock) {...}` if that passes you now have access to `$stock` value. So, you can `$product->setStock($stock - 1);`

Comment: PS: For learning this is all fine, but for production this might not be the best approach for this due to race conditions etc on baskets and checkouts. I'm only showing an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the (uncomplete) code sample you provided that you use a Symfony 4.4-ish (or earlier). I also assume that you use the Doctrine ORM ([see official Symfony doc on how to use it in a Symfony project](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller.html))

So I think you need to change your controller in order 1- to check the product's stock before adding anything to the cart and 2- to persist in base any product's stock update. Something like in the following example:

```php
public function add($id, Request $request)
    {

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $product = $this->productRepository->find($id);
        if (!$product) {

            throw $this->createNotFoundException("le produit $id n'éxiste pas");
        }
        
        $stock = $product->getStock();
        if($stock<=0){
            $this->addFlash('notice', "Sorry, no more stock");
        }
        else{
            $product->setStock($stock-1);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->cartService->add($id);
        }

        $this->addFlash('success', "le produit a bien été ajouté au panier");
        if ($request->query->get('returnToCart')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('cart_index');
        }
        if ($request->query->get('returnToHome')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('product');
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('cart_index', []);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works really good, i can make the same to decrement.